# How to modify subset of the DIV elements in a document?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eliluong/wvLrgdw2/

Let's say have an image gallery, and each image is contained within a container with a common `class` name. And I have one `div` encapsulating everything. I set up a rudimentary example in the JSFiddle code.

If a user clicked on one particular `element` in one of the images, the resulting action should do something to all of the images (or maybe a subset). The way I wrote the code was to look until you reach the top most div, and then search to reach the `div` element with the stuff I want to change. But I want to figure out how to select only a subset. I can change all of them with `$('.myB').text('bye');` but cannot change only some of them by matching on text. But  I also am unable to find a correct way to compare the strings right now. Do you have any advice you can give me? Thank you.

*Clarification -- a different question would be, can JQuery get all `myB` elements w/contents `hello2` as an array, and let me iterate through them all?

```
$('.one .myB').bind('click', function() {
    //alert('test');
    //var ttext = $(this).parentsUntil('.one').find('.myB').text();
  //$(this).parentsUntil('.one').find('.myB').text('bye');
  //$('.myB').text('bye');
  if ($('.myB').text() == "hello2") {
    $('.myB').text('bye');
  }
  //alert('text->' + ttext);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is pretty unclear. If I understand this part correctly

> I can change all of them with `$('.myB').text('bye');` but cannot change only some of them by matching on text. But I also am unable to find a correct way to compare the strings right now.

then you may want to do the following:

```
$('.one .myB').bind('click', function() {
    $(".myB").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.text().trim() === 'hello2')
        {
            $this.css('background-color', 'red'); // just for example
        }
    });
});
```

This code will **change background of all `myB` elements with text contents "hello2" when you click any `myB`**. Here is the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/wvLrgdw2/2/).

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to be able to scan all myB elements, but only change hello2 contents if user clicks on myB containing hello2. I tweaked your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/eliluong/t435g85b/. It seems to work. Is that a bad way of doing what I'm trying to accomplish? I guess a different question would be can JQuery get all myB elements w/contents hello2 as an array, and let me iterate through them all? [will add this to question]

Comment: @eluong You can use `:contains` selector: **`$(".myB:contains('hello2')")`**. However, it will return all elements having this string as a substring, but not all elements with exactly the same text.

Answer (score 2):

There could be whitespaces and empty lines inside the `<div>` tag. May be try with `trim()`:

```
if ($('.myB').text().trim() == "hello2") {
  $('.myB').text('bye');
}
```